# Redirect after GET http request in python

Tags: python, post, redirect, get, request

My simple piece of code was intended to login to web application (loginUrl - using http POST) and then go to another page within same app (theurl - using GET).

Here's my code:

```
host = 'http://myhost.mydomain:9080'
theurl = host + '/am/ve/mod/console/'#?orderBy=ORDER_BY_ADMIN_APP&order=ASC&viewBy=1&pagesize=20'

username = 'myuser'
password = 'mypass'
loginUrl = host  + '/am/en/common/j_security_check'
values = {}
values['submit'] = '1'
values['dest'] = 'null'
values['j_username'] = username
values['j_password'] = password

data = urllib.urlencode(values)
headers = {'Cache-control': 'max-age=0', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'User-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}

cookieprocessor = urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor()
http_handler = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=1)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(http_handler, cookieprocessor)

print "========================= POST request ====================="
request = urllib2.Request(loginUrl, data, headers)
opener.open(request)
print "========================= GET request ====================="
request = urllib2.Request(theurl, headers=headers, unverifiable=True)
page = opener.open(request)

print "Final url: " + page.geturl()
```

The output is:

```
========================= POST request =====================
send: 'POST /am/en/common/j_security_check HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nContent-Length: 55\r\nConnection: close\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nHost: myhost.mydomain:9080\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n'
send: 'dest=null&j_username=myuser&j_password=mypass&submit=1'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
header: Location: http://myhost.mydomain:9080/am/en/common/
header: Content-Language: en-US
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=0000AioGqwi8QbBFL0Yt1h3wLq4:-1; Path=/
header: Set-Cookie: LtpaToken2=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; Path=/
header: Connection: Close
header: Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 14:00:25 GMT
header: Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
header: Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT
header: Cache-Control: no-cache="set-cookie, set-cookie2"
send: 'GET /am/en/common/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: myhost.mydomain:9080\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: LtpaToken2=AqDVFChifqCAOm3ZYllczyUV/3hWa8tcnQx6E1/E9bA9vkT+XMflFJjhm1X2WT6ZNrix5FUO34X8dLjxYMcCujlH16Gp0NevYHu3LUtDVdopOiLDIxbqrNX9aK1hhSQaivq1uyaboYJsivmUbvKHEFftg8IDieSv0Img5ytfkEFtSL8XxRlg0sSlEADlzltydg+m5cOeOaEcJWBkYeRdOZeK+KWp/3mBInWknReiUjuUKAmvawBqomGjqfEvJdLeSWfBcPyuiVleDoX5Ww8nLstntFK/17KrGMSzVaX+KDF9hMCkQWq6yZIU76nousJMXw5mAKXlWQI5K74QYTqM/mI6uxLq57CCZdBtHDaHRvFIiMWP2kWxQab0JOLwamYTWWoDo7Dq4NTUH2zAjUn/6Rb08Bwq5yB6LG3TYZFsItV8no7cZ59tmgCz/C8HyWVpilnuv8fF9UU++z9e9awwoo1gzdhRy3ZeippAmUGrKHiu3EN6vREE27oDVRNeIjIMfE26LDsuDLiZt+u2B12xR+kWKxCiPzSi00olR/2tfwoIBU6LU7fvs57OiNhOW9SrjinYeNrawbVBdcQQhsGRZhvrBmeW3N0oOjqVRerWAsQrTEneqrJ4P/gV6zLN4V6V; JSESSIONID=0000AioGqwi8QbBFL0Yt1h3wLq4:-1\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
header: Content-Language: en-US
header: Content-Length: 1323
header: Connection: Close
header: Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 14:00:26 GMT
header: Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
========================= GET request =====================
send: 'GET /am/ve/mod/console/ HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: myhost.mydomain:9080\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: LtpaToken2=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; JSESSIONID=0000AioGqwi8QbBFL0Yt1h3wLq4:-1\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
header: Cache-Control: no-cache
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: -1
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
header: Location: http://myhost.mydomain:9080/am/ve/login?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.mydomain%3A9080%2Fam%2Fve%2Fmod%2Fconsole%2F&rand=1333461626691
header: Content-Language: en
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Connection: Close
header: Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 14:00:26 GMT
header: Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
send: 'GET /am/ve/login?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.mydomain%3A9080%2Fam%2Fve%2Fmod%2Fconsole%2F&rand=1333461626691 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: myhost.mydomain:9080\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: LtpaToken2=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; JSESSIONID=0000AioGqwi8QbBFL0Yt1h3wLq4:-1\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 302 Found\r\n'
header: Cache-Control: no-cache
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: -1
header: Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
header: Location: http://myhost.mydomain:9080/am/home?rand=1333461626997
header: Content-Language: en
header: Content-Length: 0
header: Connection: Close
header: Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 14:00:26 GMT
header: Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
send: 'GET /am/home?rand=1333461626997 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: myhost.mydomain:9080\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: LtpaToken2=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; JSESSIONID=0000AioGqwi8QbBFL0Yt1h3wLq4:-1\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n'
reply: 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n'
header: Cache-Control: no-cache
header: Pragma: no-cache
header: Expires: -1
header: Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
header: Content-Language: en
header: Transfer-Encoding: chunked
header: Connection: Close
header: Date: Tue, 03 Apr 2012 14:00:27 GMT
header: Server: WebSphere Application Server/7.0
Final url: http://myhost.mydomain:9080/am/home?rand=1333461626997
```

It seems that after GET request i got three redirects for some reasons. Probably this one is causing I can't go to the URL I would like to:

```
send: 'GET /am/ve/login?dest=http%3A%2F%2Fmyhost.mydomain%3A9080%2Fam%2Fve%2Fmod%2Fconsole%2F&rand=1333461626691 HTTP/1.1\r\nAccept-Encoding: identity\r\nHost: myhost.mydomain:9080\r\nUser-Agent: Mozilla/5.0\r\nConnection: close\r\nCookie: LtpaToken2=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; JSESSIONID=0000AioGqwi8QbBFL0Yt1h3wLq4:-1\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\nCache-Control: max-age=0\r\n\r\n'
```

I don't know how to get rid of that. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: You get redirects because the server is sending you redirects. What do you want to achieve, and how is your code not achieving it now?

Comment: I want to reach the url specified in theurl property (theurl = host + '/am/ve/mod/console/). Server is redirecting me to http://myhost.mydomain:9080/am/home?rand=1333461626997
(see the bottom of the output). Dzięki ;)

Comment: You are reaching the url you specify; that URL is redirected.

Comment: But I dont want it to be redirected. I can reach the URL via browser without being redirected and this is exactly what i want to achieve.

Comment: I imagine that what you are seeing is the end of the redirect chain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use some kind of a logging tunnel or something (like Apache's TcpTunnelGui) and check what exactly is your browser sending (and the server returning) when it's working? Then do the same in the script. :)